# Tiny C - Точка входа в процедуру CryptAcquireContextA не найдена в библиотеке DLL

Tags: c, winapi

project.c

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")

int main()
{
    HCRYPTPROV hProv;
    CryptAcquireContextA(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);
    return 0;
}
```

Компилирую, так же указывая на дополнительный include где присутствует заголовок wincrypt.h:

```
tcc -c project.c -I "..\winapi-full-for-0.9.27\include\winapi"
```

Далее:

```
tcc project.o -o project.exe -lcrypt32
```

Происходит ошибка:

```
tcc: error: undefined symbol '_CryptAcquireContextA@20'
```

Пробую как описано здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243579/tcc-error-undefined-symbol-getconsolewindow0 - создаю в директории lib файл crypt32.def с таким содержимым:

```
LIBRARY crypt32.dll

EXPORTS
CryptAcquireContextA
```

Компиляция проходит без ошибок. Но при запуске приложения выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
Точка входа в процедуру CryptAcquireContextA не найдена в библиотеке DLL
```

Как быть? При компиляции через MinGW все работает. Выбрал TCC из за малого размера бинарника.

Comment: CryptAcquireContext давно deprecated. Проверил на Windows 10 - в x64-версии DLL такой функции в природе нет, в x86 - есть, но только с именем CryptAcquireContextU. Рассказывайте, что именно в MinGW работает, на какой ОС и какая разрядность приложения.

Comment: А, ерунду написал. CryptAcquireContext - в Advapi32.dll, а не в crypt32. Все там есть в Windows 10.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, спасибо большое. Два дня бился об заклад, нужно было tcc project.o -o project.exe  -ladvapi32, незнаю с чего я взял что это в crypt32. Добавьте ответ полный.

Comment: `#pragma comment` - это фича Visual Studio. На что вы надеялись, пытаясь делать это в TinyC?

Comment: @AnT, незнаю для чего фича. Брал код из примера, который видать для VS предназначался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция CryptAcquireContextA находится в Advapi32.dll, а не в crypt32.dll (см. [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptacquirecontexta#requirements)). Поэтому нужно собирать так:

```
tcc project.o -o project.exe -ladvapi32
```